# Law of Demeter and DAO pattern

Tags: spring, dao, law-of-demeter

Here's a method in my Spring/Hibernate website's code that exemplifies my codebase:

```
public class UserVoteServiceImpl implements UserVoteService {

   @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

   public static int getUserScore(long userId) {
     return userRepository.findUserById(userId).getScore();
   }
 }
```

I believe that this method violates the Law of Demeter, since it is making calls on the object returned by findUserById().  How can I change this code to obey the Principle of Least Knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a violation of the Law of Demeter. It would be a violation if you were passing in some object, getting userId off of it, and using only the userid.

Here's an example that would be a violation:

```
public class UserVoteServiceImpl implements UserVoteService {

   @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

   public static int getUserScore(SomeWrapper someWrapper) {
     return userRepository.findUserById(someWrapper.getUserId()).getScore();
   }
 }
```

But there's nothing wrong with delegating work within the implementation of your method, and there's nothing wrong with making a call on the object returned from the repository.

(Personally I'm not crazy about using services to wrap single dao calls, but that's a different problem.)

Currently I'm working on a codebase perpetrated by people who apparently never heard of LoD, full of stuff like

```
public Thing getThing(Integer id) {
    return new Beta().getGamma().getDelta().getEpsilon().getOmega().getThing(id);
}
```

and initially I thought your example didn't rise to the same level of pathology as that. But after reading [this blog post, which is where I got the above example, of course](http://dnicolet1.tripod.com/agile/index.blog?entry_id=2057162),
I think I'd recommend you changing your method to

```
public class UserVoteServiceImpl implements UserVoteService {

   @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

   public User getUser(Long userId) {
     return userRepository.findUserById(userId);
   }
 }
```

and letting the caller pull the score off the User. This change also has the benefit of having the application's service interface deal in domain objects, not in primitives.